# Fastcgi: php is not connected with mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, ubuntu, fastcgi

I have 2 different php versions running. They are running fine but they are not connected to mysql and I dont know why. They should be and I dont know how I can force them to connect with mysql.

The php versions are 5.3.27 and 5.4.31
If u need any more information, let me know.

Comment: Maybe blocked port? What distro of Linux?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @ChristianMark: I am using Ubuntu 14.04.1. It's using the default port. Because it is running on a virtual machine (mysql and the 2 php versions) I think this should not be a problem.

Comment: @DeeJay': Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_get_client_info()

is the exact error

Comment: It means that your MySql extension is not installed/enabled in the instance of PHP. Check your php.ini file and install it. I will post an answer for this.

Comment: Short inormation, i was following this tutorial: http://www.distrogeeks.com/install-multiple-php-versions-in-ubuntu-lamp-server/

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following command to install mysql client for php and enable it in php.ini

`sudo apt-get install mysql-server libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql`

Make sure to restart apache (or any web server you are using) before you try to see any changes.

Digital Ocean provides easy guides on installing LAMP environment. Have a look here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

It's working now. I just mistyped "extension=mysql.so" :/

Anyways thanks for trying to help!

Comment: Told you it needs to be enabled in php.ini